# Python good programming practice for enumerating lists

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general, and I was wondering if it is a good programming practice to write long statements with many logic operators - for example, in a for loop.

For example, here's a function I made that gets all the vowels from a word and returns a list containing those vowels.

```
def getVowels(word):
    vowel_list = []
    index = 0
    for i in word:
        if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u" or i == "A" or i == "E" or i == "I" or i == "O" or i == "U":
            vowel_list.append(word[index])
        index += 1
    return vowel_list
```

As you can see, the if statement has gotten very long. Is it considered good programming? If it's not, is there a better way to code this function?

Comment: You should use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of a counter.

Comment: This is a good question. Be sure to accept an answer in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No it is not considered good practice, there are always better ways :D

```
if i.upper() in "AEIOU"
```

Here is a much shorter version of your function using list comprehensions:

```
def get_vowels(word):
    vowels = "AEIOU"
    return [c for c in word if c.upper() in vowels]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know i can use "in" for strings too , i thought i can only use it for lists. But as strings behave almost the same as lists, i should've known that .d 
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of shortcuts :D

Comment: @geekkid The ability to compress your code down to this answer is pretty much what python is all about - it really enables concise, non-repetitive coding.

Comment: Just as a minor nitpick, Python tends to use `underscored_names` like `get_vowels`.

Comment: Also `str.upper()` isn't polite to use on Unicode (what is `'и'.upper()`?) It would be better (and more concise!) to test upper and lowercase explicitly: `if i in "AEIOUaeiou"`.

Answer (score 4):

Would probably be better to use sets:

```
VOWELS = set('aeiouAUIOU')

def get_vowels(word):
    return [c for c in word if c in VOWELS]
```

or, more geeky:

```
def get_vowels(word):
    return filter(VOWELS.__contains__, word)
```

(But the first approach is most readable and as such is more pythonic. Also, the second function will return generator, not a list in Python 3.)

**EDIT** performance comparison of `c in list` vs `c in set`:

```
import timeit

VOWELS = 'aeiouAEIOU'
VOWSET = set(VOWELS)
SAMPLE = 'asflasrjoperugASDFAROUAoarfpeoriugargagadropgue'

def get_vowels(word, vowels):
    return [c for c in word if c in vowels]

print timeit.timeit('get_vowels(SAMPLE, VOWELS)', 
                    'from __main__ import VOWELS, SAMPLE, get_vowels') 
# ^ prints 10.0739870071
print timeit.timeit('get_vowels(SAMPLE, VOWSET)', 
                    'from __main__ import VOWSET, SAMPLE, get_vowels') 
# ^ prints 9.43965697289
```

Comment: Your last function doesn't produce the vowels in the word, it just says `True` or `False`

Comment: @jamylak oh shame on me. Thanks, removing.

Comment: Is using sets make it faster? Because VOWELS = 'aeiouAUIOU' also works.

Comment: @Akavall yes, it's marginally faster, updated with `timeit` output. For sequences longer than `aeiouAEIOU` difference will be more significant.

Comment: Set contains is average-case constant time, list is linear time. The number of characters is tiny here so it makes almost no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` is the same as:

```
if i in "aeiouAEIOU"
```

Basically you're checking for member in a set.

Comment: @agf They're equivalent if we assume `word` is a string

Answer (score 1):

I think long statements are harder to understand than short ones.  There is almost always a way to do the same thing with shorter statements.  In your case, you can simplify the if like this:

```
def getVowels(word):
    vowel_list = []
    for i in word:
        if i in "aeiouAEIOU":
            vowel_list.append(i)
    return vowel_list
```

since Python allows you to use the "in" operator to search for one string inside another.

But Python also allows list comprehensions, which simplify loops:

```
def getVowels(word):
    return [i for i in word if i in "aeiouAEIOU"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like:

```
set('aeiouAUIOU') & set(word)
```

Comment: Ooh, pretty...
Except that scrambles the letters, and doesn't preserve duplicates.

Comment: Yes, and yes, but too pretty to miss out.