# Cannot determine vowels from consonants

Tags: python, character

With the code below, no matter what the first letter of the input is, it is always determined as a vowel:

```
original = raw_input("Please type in a word: ")
firstLetter = original[0]
print firstLetter

if firstLetter == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
    print "vowel"
else:
    print "consonant"
```

In fact, it doesn't matter what the boolean is in the if statement... if it is == or != , it is still return `"vowel"`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is not the English language. If you have a bunch of expressions with `or` or `and` between them, each one must make sense on its own. Note that on its own:

```
if "e":
    print("something")
```

will always print `something`, even if `letter` doesn't equal `"e"`.

You need to do it like this:

```
if letter == "a" or letter == "e"  # (...)
```

Or, more concisely:

```
if letter in "aeiouy":
```

Comment: I see! So basically using **in** is the equivalent of multiple **or** in a way?

Comment: `in` is pretty much what you'd expect. `thing in seq` is true if `seq` has an element equal to `thing`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if firstLetter in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
```

what your test does is the following:

```
if (firstLetter == "a") or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
```

and each of the latter 4 tests is true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your Boolean expression:

```
firstLetter = 'a'
firstLetter in 'aeiou' 
True

firstLetter = 'x'
firstLetter in 'aeiou' 
False
```

This is equivalent to

```
      firstLetter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

i.e., you want to put this into your if statement like this:

```
if firstLetter  in 'aeiou':
   print 'vowel'
else:
   print 'consonant'
```

*Note*:

Your original approach was on the right track, but you would have had to compare each letter separetely like

```
if firstLetter == 'a' or firstLetter == 'e' or firstLetter == 'i' or ...
```

Using the above is much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Your test doesn't work like you think it does. You are asking, "If the variable equals 'a'", then the rest of your test basically asks if the letters e, i, o or u are False. Only an empty string evaluates to False (try "e" == False in the interpreter to see). Use the "in" test from other answers. Also, make sure to lower-case firstLetter so you're always comparing like to like.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know how `or` works, it evaluates both the left and right expression and it returns the first expression that evaluates true, otherwise it returns the last expression:

From this [source](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) you can see that all of these evaluate false:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.3.1

---

```
>>> False or True
True
>>> '' or False
False
>>> '' or 0
0
```

So a non-empty string will evaluate as true and it will be returned:

```
>>> 'abc' or False
'abc
```

---

```
 if firstLetter == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
     print "vowel"
 else:
     print "consonant"
```

For a string `'foo'`,  `'f'` is the first letter.
In the first part of your code, `firstLetter == "a" or "e"`, the left expression will evaluate as false, but `'e'` is not an empty string so it evaluates as true and it will `print "vowel"`

You can see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055045/python-good-programming-practice-for-enumerating-lists/10055062#10055062) which answers your question, something like this:

```
if c.upper() in "AEIOU"
```

will check if a letter is a vowel.