# forloop in python pig latin translator

Tags: python

I've been trying to work on a pig latin translator in python and I had setup a forloop to loop through each character of a user-entered string.  To test that the forloop is successfully  catching all the consonants that follow the initial consonant until it hits a vowel(e.g. "str" in the word "string"), I had written a print statement to print out all of these consecutive consonants in a word that begins with a consonant.  Unfortunately, the forloop only omits the letter "a" but allows the vowels "e" "i" "o" and "u" to be printed.

**So my question here is how can I fix this code so that only the first string of consonants until the first vowel of the entered word?**

I'm not particularly equipped with the language to describe the process by which I'm doing this but hopefully this plea is a close enough approximation that helps express the nature of the problem.  Thanks.

code:

```
def translate():
     print("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator")
     original=raw_input("What word would you like to translate?")
     length=len(original)
     move_letters=""
     index=0
     for i in range(length):
        if original[i]!=("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u"):
            print(original[i])
            move_letters=move_letters+original[i]
            index+=1


translate()
```

Comment: http://www.mit.edu/~johnp/6.189/solutions/piglatin.py

Comment: The answers to this question should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809126/cannot-determine-vowels-from-consonants/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u")
```

is equivalent to `"a"`.  This is why your code is only catching `"a"`.  You need to write:

```
if not original[i] in ("a","e","i","o","u") :
```

or

```
if original[i] != "a" and original[i] != "e" and original[i] != "i" and original[i] != "o" and original[i] != "u" :
```

The reason why `("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u")` is equivalent to `"a"` is that, according to its definition, the `or` operator returns the first operand equivalent to true or `0` if there is none.  In this case, '"a"' is equivalent to true, so it is the result of the whole expression.

You also need to add:

```
else:
    break
```

to the `if`.